# PHP Post data from one page to another page

Tags: php, post

I used the following code to post the values from one page to another page but don't know why for some reason the values are not posted. Can anyone help me correcting the below code, thanks.

```
<?php
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'destinationId' => 'E5322331-EB43-4C45-B5B1-00E455401676',
        'keywords' => 'Rambouillet, France'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result   = file_get_contents('https://dev.ther8server.com/hotel-search/go/rambouillet-france', false, $context);
header('Location:https://dev.ther8server.com/hotel-search/go/rambouillet-france');
?>
```

Comment: You redirect to the page using header. This creates a completely seperate request from the one created with file_get_contents.

Comment: Are you expecting this code to redirect you to the page you posted to and be able to debug the posted data? `stream_context_create` is more like a curl call. If you are trying to make persistent data between pages, try using session variables instead.

Comment: I want to transfer data from this page to another as page is not redirecting automatically I used `header Location` for redirection purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This code causes PHP to post a form, get the $result page... and then ignore all that and redirect the client to another page.

Instead of of the header Location, you just want to `echo $result;`